# Extract unique values from a range in excel while disregarding specific values

Tags: excel, arraylist, unique-values

I originally had an Excel spreadsheet which was used to record values of JOB LOT IDs (>10000). I used the following array formula -

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($C$3:$S$52<>"")*(COUNTIF($V$3:V3,$C$3:$S$52)=0),ROW($3:$52)*100+COLUMN($C$S),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""
```

Data:

```
| pallet    | Lot#      | Lot#      | Lot#      | Lot#      | Lot#      |
|--------   |-------    |-------    |--------   |-------    |--------   |
| 1         | 12345     | 12346     | 12345     | 12347     | 123456    |
| 2         | 12345     | 12346     | 12348     | 12348     | 12343     |
| 3         | 12345     | 12347     | 123456    | 12348     | 12348     |
```

This worked fine if the cells in that range all represented the JOB LOT IDs.
It would record the unique LOT #'s as I copied this into the result range and coupled with the counting formula

```
(IF(LEN(V4)>0,COUNTIF($C$3:$S$52,V4),"")
```

in the adjacent cell. It returned:

```
Unique  
Value  Count
______ _____
12345    4   
12346    2   
12347    2  
123456   2 
12348    4 
12343    1
```

Unfortunately, the scope of the job and spreadsheet changed such that the spreadsheet needed to include columns before each JOB LOT cell to record the Case# of the JOB LOT.

What I need help with is figuring out how to disregard the case# data, which will always be between 1 and 451, and only count the unique JOB LOT IDs, which will always be > 100000. Resulting in only the unique list of Job Numbers. Using the same array formula with the added column for Case#, the Case Numbers are also listed, when they are not needed or wanted.

```
| pallet    | case#     | Lot#      | case#     | Lot#      | case#     | Lot#      | case#     | Lot#      | case#     | Lot#      |
|--------   |-------    |-------    |-------    |-------    |-------    |--------   |-------    |-------    |-------    |--------   |
| 1         | 1         | 12345     | 45        | 12346     | 356       | 12345     | 6         | 12347     | 7         | 123456    |
| 2         | 3         | 12345     | 35        | 12346     | 212       | 12348     | 23        | 12348     | 200       | 12343     |
| 3         | 54        | 12345     | 34        | 12347     | 450       | 123456    | 345       | 12348     | 367       | 12348     |
```

The result is

```
Unique
Value   Count
______  _____
12345     4  
45        1
12346     2 
356       1
6         1
12347     2 
7         1  
123456    2 
35        1 
212       1 
12348     4 
23        1 
200       1 
12343     1 
34        1 
450       1 
345       1 
367       1
```

Any Suugestions?
Thanks.

Comment: @QHarr - did so - and edited, don't see this as being any better than the original but your wish has been granted...

Comment: Is that better? Thanks.

Comment: Once again thanks for your input.

Comment: Would you be open to a vba solution? Does your data start in column A and is the pattern always  pallet    | case#     | Lot#      | case#     | Lot#    | case#     | Lot#    etc....

Comment: Yes, would be open to VBA and yes the pattern is as described...

Comment: Why not just add an additional clause re >10000? =INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF($C$3:$S$52>10000,IF(COUNTIF($V$3:V3,$C$3:$S$52)=0,10^5*ROW($C$3:$S$52)+COLUMN($C$3:$S$52)))),"R0C00000"),0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to hold the unique `Lot#` as keys and add one to the value associated with this key each time the key is encountered again.

The data is read in from the sheet, from column C to the right most column, into an array, `arr`. `arr` is looped only looking at every other column i.e. the `Lot#` columns. The contents of the dictionary i.e. the unique `Lot#` (`Keys`) and count of them (`Items`), are written out to sheet2.

It assumes your data starts in A1 and has the layout given in the question.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetUniqueValueByCounts()
    Dim arr(), i As Long, j As Long, dict As Object, lastColumn As Long, lastRow As Long
    Const NUMBER_COLUMNS_TO_SKIP = 2
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If lastColumn < 3 Or lastRow < 2 Then Exit Sub

        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Value

        For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) Step NUMBER_COLUMNS_TO_SKIP
            For j = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
               If arr(j, i) <> vbNullString Then
                   dict(arr(j, i)) = dict(arr(j, i)) + 1
               End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
        .Range("B1").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Ordered results:**

You can use a `sortedList` to get ordered results though you lose the nice `.Keys` and `.Items` methods of generating arrays in one go to write to the sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetUniqueValueByCounts()
    Dim arr(), i As Long, j As Long, dict As Object, lastColumn As Long, lastRow As Long, list As Object
    Const NUMBER_COLUMNS_TO_SKIP = 2
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If lastColumn < 3 Or lastRow < 2 Then Exit Sub

        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Value

        For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) Step NUMBER_COLUMNS_TO_SKIP
            For j = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                If arr(j, i) <> vbNullString Then
                    With list
                        If Not .contains(arr(j, i)) Then
                            list.Add arr(j, i), 1
                        Else
                            list(arr(j, i)) = list(arr(j, i)) + 1
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        Next i
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For j = 0 To list.Count - 1
            .Cells(j + 1, 1) = list.GetKey(j)
            .Cells(j + 1, 2) = list.GetByIndex(j)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a shot.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a shot. Needs some work to fit the actual spreadsheet but am going through it now to correct. With the same data in an excel spreadsheet, the data range is B3..S52. The code provided is counting blanks and missing some values. As stated trying to figure out why.

Comment: Thanks All Set - the issue was the line of code that figured out the lastColumn - when I forced it to set to 19, all was ok. Thanks for the code! Cheers!

Comment: Spoke to soon - it throws an error when checking for a blank in the list. In the code:               With list
                    If Not .contains(arr(j, i)) Then
                        list.Add arr(j, i), 1
                    Else
                        list(arr(j, i)) = list(arr(j, i)) + 1
                    End If
                End With
The value for arr(4,1) is blank and the error thrown is RunTime:'-2147467261 (80004003)' Key Cannot be null. Parameter name: Key

Comment: I modified your original - not needing the sort function at all to be the following:

Comment: Yes all set this was very helpful. Thank you!